# If 2 nodes started simultaneously, they don't see each other

Tags: java, hazelcast

I was trying to start 2 hazelcast nodes simultaneously, and they can not discover each other. It's true for both multicast and tcp-ip discovery.
If I restart one node later - they see each other.
Is there a way to make them discover each other without restarting? Or how to postpone discovery during node start-up?

Configuration:

```
    <network>
    <port auto-increment="true">5701</port>
    <outbound-ports>
        <!--
        Allowed port range when connecting to other nodes.
        0 or * means use system provided port.
        -->
        <ports>0</ports>
    </outbound-ports>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="true">
            <multicast-group>224.3.3.6</multicast-group>
            <multicast-port>5705</multicast-port>
        </multicast>
    </join>
</network>
```

or

```
        <multicast enabled="false">
            <multicast-group>224.3.3.6</multicast-group>
            <multicast-port>5705</multicast-port>
        </multicast>
        <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <member>host1:5701</member>
            <member>host2:5701</member>
            <member>host3:5701</member>
            <member>host4:5701</member>
        </tcp-ip>
```

UPD: Solved by manually add random sleep on startup before cluster init.

Comment: I can postpone member creation (Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);). But is doesn't seem as a nice solution

Comment: They should really find each other. Have you listed the both their addresses in the config? Can you show your config?

Comment: I guess <multicast-timeout-seconds> and <multicast-time-to-live> has something to do about it, but exactly impact of these options is unclear to me

Comment: It is very strange that the nodes can't find each other when they are started concurrently. So I guess it is related to you environment since this problem is new to me. Can you post some of your logging so we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Are your nodes running sufficiently long? In my experience, it can take quite a while (30 seconds) until the nodes find each other - independent of the discovery communication (multicast vs TCPIP).

[After several trials and erros, Hazelcast.com and me found quite a simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385973/how-do-you-programmatically-configure-hazelcast-for-the-multicast-discovery-mech):

```
config.setProperty("hazelcast.initial.min.cluster.size","2");
```

In my experiments, the solution is faster and more stable than waiting for a while.